# How to truncate a table in web api using EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUCATE Table Nlog")--
```

I get an error from this code:

> int does not contain a definition for get awaiter

I tried a stored procedure which just truncates the table. But that is also causing an error as required Id field is not present.

Comment: You have misspelled Truncate in your command

Comment: @Henkie85 Thank you for correcting me, but it didnot solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command that you are using is not an asynchronous command.  Remove the await or use

```
await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("TRUNCATE Table Nlog").
```

Also, keep in mind that you can only truncate a table if the records are not being referenced by other tables. If they are being referenced, you need to truncate those tables first before truncating this one.

Comment: Solved my issue removing await